# data from nested json response

Tags: c#, json

I want to get the 'id' from the JSON given below. Please suggest

```
{
    "User": {
        "User": {
            "id": "3",
            "first_name": "ABC",
            "last_name": "Kumar",
            "email": "vinod.kumar@abc.com",
            "role": "admin"
        }
    }
}
```

I have used below code for deserialization. But unable to access id from json.

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
//var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Usercontent);
Object LoginUser = serializer.DeserializeObject(LoginUserDetails);
Dictionary<string, object> countList = (Dictionary<string, object>)LoginUser;
```

Comment: Are you able to get the other properties? Does your `LoginUserDetails` type *have* an `Id` property? It's not clear why you have this nesting to start with, mind you.

Answer (score 1):

Nested Json require nested classes.

```
//json string... I had to remove the double quotes to make it clearer.
string jsonString = @"{
    'User': {
        'User': {
            'id': '3',
            'first_name': 'ABC',
            'last_name': 'Kumar',
            'email': 'vinod.kumar@abc.com',
            'role': 'admin'
        }
    }
}";

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
object obj = js.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(User1));
User1 k = (User1)obj;

//id can be accessed by
int userid = k.User.User.id;

//nested user class
namespace JsonTest
{
    //main user
    public class User1
    {
        public User2 User;
    }
    //user2 is nested in user 1
    public class User2
    {
        public User User;
    }
    //final user is nested in User2.
    //note that the property name is User in all cases.
    public class User
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string role { get; set; }
    }


}
```